# How to construct a plot to see the impact of regularization to Test and Training score

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I tried to construct a consecutive plot to see the impact of regularization of Lasso and Ridge regression to the Training and Test Score. But I had an error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I googled some suggestions but still cannot figure it out. Does anyone have a better idea?
Here's how I made the data and plot:

```
# Define how to generate float range using itertools
from itertools import islice, count
def iter_range(start, stop, step):
    if step == 0:
    raise ValueError("Step could not be NULL")
    length = int(abs(stop - start) / step)
    return islice(count(start, step), length)

# Ridge
Train_r = []
Test_r = []
for i in iter_range(0.1,10,0.1):
    ridge = Ridge(alpha=i).fit(X_train, y_train)
    Train = ridge.score(X_train, y_train)
    Test = ridge.score(X_test, y_test)
    Train_r.append(Train)
    Test_r.append(Test)
print(Train_r)
print(Test_r)

# Lasso
Train_l = []
Test_l = []
for i in iter_range(0.001,1,0.001):
    lasso = Lasso(alpha=i, max_iter=10000).fit(X_train, y_train)
    Train = lasso.score(X_train, y_train)
    Test = lasso.score(X_test, y_test)
    Train_l.append(Train)
    Test_l.append(Test)
print(Train_l)
print(Test_l)

# Plotting
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 4))
x1 = np.arange(1,0.001,0.001)
x1 = x1.reshape(-1,1)
y1_1 = np.array([Train_l])
y1_2 = np.array([Test_l])

x2 = np.arange(0.1,10,0.1)
x2 = x2.reshape(-1,1)
y2_1 = np.array([Train_r])
y2_2 = np.array([Test_r])

axes[0].plot(x1, y1_1, x1, y1_2)
axes[0].set_title("Alpha for Lasso Regression")
axes[0].legend(labels=['Training Score', 'Test Score'])

axes[1].plot(x2, y2_1, x2, y2_2)
axes[1].axis('tight')
axes[1].set_title("Alpha for Ridge Regression")
axes[1].legend(labels=['Training Score', 'Test Score'])
```

Here's the error
[image]

Comment: can you provide full traceback error ?

Comment: Yes, I just added it. Thank you.

Comment: can you try `x.reshape(-1,1)` instead ?

Comment: I tried. But it still failed. : (